# Basic way to do user authentication for codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter

My current solution is to:

Create a `authentication_model`.

and write my authentication in the `__constructor` of each controller that needs a user logged in. Very simple and easy to understand.

My other option is to make a My_controller and do my authentication there and extend it with all controllers that need a user logged in.

Problem is, the answers ive gotten from this varies, some only use My_controller but some have base_controller and auth_controller.

And i'm confused if a single My_controller for authentication is enough or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you are using Ion_Auth (I can recommend it). Now, if your site is 99% behind an auth system a `MY_Controller` with a `__construct` that looks like this should be sufficient for all of the controllers requiring auth:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
            redirect('login');
        }
    }
}
```

and then in the `login` controller (e.g. user isn't logged in yet) you simply extend `CI_Controller` so you don't end up in a redirect loop.

The issue with this approach becomes apparent if you are like me and have separate frontend and backend running on the same CI installation. In such a case you have you public controllers in your main CI controllers directory and a sub-directory in controllers called `auth`. Again, in my case, the frontend and backend share similar resources but I don't want to bog down the frontend by autoloading `Ion_Auth` and the `users_model` and all the models that make my backend work as its not required functionality.

So I only autoload things I use in both such as sessions and database and then have a `Shared_Controller` that extends `CI_Controller` that sets up some public variables that I use in both. Then I have a `Auth_Controller` that extends the `Shared_Controller` and uses a similar approach as the code above; in that `__construct` I load what I would have autoloaded had I not had a "separate" frontend (such as `Ion_Auth` .etc.) and just make the `login` controller a special case that does not get redirected.

I then also have a `Frontend_Controller` also extending `Shared_Controller` that loads some things I use throughout the frontend controllers.

So as you can see it largely depends on what you are trying to accomplish. There is no right or wrong way just left and right.

Comment: You lost me there when you mentioned those backend/frontend controller.

I really don't want to use ion_auth as i don't need the extra functionality other than a login system. 

Can i just make an auth_model and check there if the session logged in exists in the user table and return true/false and in the constructor in the My_Controller just put an if statement if its false redirect to login page if not do nothing?

Comment: Yes that would be in-line with the first thing I mentioned in my answer. And Ion Auth is a login system... do you mean you don't want to support one user and that's it? in which case, id agree that its overkill

Comment: I mean i only need the basics of a login system.

Register/Login. I tried to use ion auth once and there were alot of things going on Like email activation,remember me. 

If i were to use ion auth it wouldnt be different than copy pasting codes i dont fully understand.

Comment: I get you but at the same time if you are having users registering a lot of that other functionality such as forgot password forms and activation are sort of a prerequisite. I will say that Ion Auth provides a good examples controller that should make everything pretty clear (if not you should be able to figure it out after learning CI a bit more). I'm not a spokesperson I promise - just want to save you the trouble of starting a new system and realizing you need more functionality than you previously thought (been there).